# Overwrite proj property with msbuild switch

Tags: .net, msbuild

Given the following proj snippet:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="artifacts" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <msbuild40>"msbuild.exe"</msbuild40>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="compile">
        <Exec Command="$(msbuild40) src\ClientFrameworkLoader.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug;platform=win32" />
        <Exec Command="$(msbuild40) src\ClientFrameworkLoader.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;platform=win32" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

am I right in thinking I can overwrite the `msbuild40` property using the following command?

```
MSBuild.exe snippet.proj /p:msbuild40="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

*I don't have a Windows machine to hand right now otherwise I'd just try this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can override the property like that. However you'll need to put quotes around the invoked command since it contains spaces. Escaped quotes in msbuild are `$quot;` Also a more msbuild way of doing this is to not repeat yourself and put both configurations you want to build in an ItemGroup and loop over it. Applying these modifications gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="artifacts" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <msbuild40>"msbuild.exe"</msbuild40>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Configurations Include="Debug;Release"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="compile">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(msbuild40)&quot; src\ClientFrameworkLoader.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=%(Configurations.Identity);platform=win32" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

That being said it's probably wise to do test in on a windows machine before sending it into the wild :P